# file running with no assertion at release but shows assertion at debug mode

Tags: debugging, visual-c++, mfc, release

I'm working a project which work fine at release mode but through an debug assertion at debug mode. I already look into the project properties of both mode but they is no change  in them + the path which the debug assertion occurred doesn't exists in my PC didn't understand the unrealistic behavior of this app any possible solution and guidance  [this is there assertion but the path D:\a.... dose not exists in my PC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9a4L.png) . and if possible how can we disable the assertion box

Comment: Click on "Retry". This will break into the debugger and show you the exact location in the MFC source code where the ASSERT happened. This will give you valuable information about what has gone wrong. You also can examine the stack trace, which will get you to the exact line of your code that triggers the problem. Don't bother about the "D:\..." it's misleading. [Edit] and share that informatino with us, then we can help. Without further information we can't help much.

Comment: *"a project which work fine at release mode"* - It doesn't. The fact that it won't display a failed assertion dialog in a release configuration is solely the result of debug assertions getting stripped out from a release configuration. The bug is still there. Use the debug configuration to, well, debug the issue. There are instructions on the dialog.